# Using java to input information onto a webpage from a text file

Tags: java, html, parsing

i'm building a program to take information from one webpage and enter it into another, parsing the original page for the information isn't a problem, but I have no idea how to get that information from the text file and into the text fields of a different website using a script. Google isn't helping, so can this be done with java?

Comment: Explain - do you want to fill out a form and submit it by program?

Comment: @fvu - I think the OP is wanting to do some cURL sorcery to submit data by form without being all clicky with a mouse and keyboard (humans...).

Comment: Have a look at Apache HttpComponents, a long tutorial: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/tutorial/html/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is how to submit a form programmatically in Java, I would suggest to look at [Apache HTTP Components Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html), a class library that does all the hard work for you.

The documentation is very good so I suggest you first read at least [their tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html), but here's a small code fragment I borrowed from their website that shows how to POST a form with variables user and password

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://jakarata.apache.org/");
NameValuePair[] data = {
  new NameValuePair("user", "joe"),
  new NameValuePair("password", "bloggs")
};
post.setRequestBody(data);
// execute method and handle any error responses.
...
InputStream in = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
// handle response.
```

Now, I agree with Marijn and Jared, if this is a one shot it's probably just not worth it, and some creative scripting with eg cURL or Selenium would be a much faster way to solve your problem.

Comment: Cheers for the ideas, its something important that i'll be doing every day, so i figured i'd make a script

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 routes you can take to do this:

1) Use a library like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga) and post the information you gathered directly to the website.

2) Use a web testing framework like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to interact with a browser and fill out the form.

Option 1 is by far the most robust and fastest, but (2) let's you make use of any client side code (javascript) the target may rely on.